# Python strange "string indices must be integers" error

Tags: python

**Problem solved!** was newfilename[0,3] instead of newfilename[0: 3]

I know this question has been asked before and I have look around on all the answers and the types of problems people have been having related to this error message, but was unable to find anyone with the same type of problem.

I am sowing the whole method just in case. So here is **my problem**;

**When I am trying to get** is a substring of "newfilename" using newfilename[int, int] and the compiler keeps thinking I don't have an integer there when I do, at least from my checking I do.

**What I'm doing with this code:** I am cutting of the end of a filename such as 'foo.txt' to get 'foo' that is saved as newfilename. Then I am adding the number (converted to a string) to the end of it to get 'foo 1' and after that adding back the '.txt' to get the final result of 'foo 1.txt'. The problem occurs when I try to get the substring out and delete the last four characters of the filename to get just 'foo'. After that, I do another check to see if there is a file like that still in the folder and if so I do another set of cutting and pasting to add 1 to the previous file. To be honest, I have not tested of the while loop will work I just thought it should work technically, but my code does not reach that far because of this error lol.

**My error:**

```
File "C:/Users/Reaper/IdeaProjects/Curch Rec Managment/Setup.py", line 243, in moveFiles
    print(newfilename[0, 3])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

*NOTE this error is from when I tried to hard code the numbers it to see if it would work*

Here is the current error with the hard code commented out:

```
    newfilename = newfilename[0, int(newfilename.__len__() - 4)] + " 1.m4a"
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**What I have tried:** I have tried hard coding the numbers is by literally typing in newfilename[0, 7] and still got the same error. I have tried doing this in a separate python file and it seems to work there fine. Also, what is really confusing me is that it works in another part of my program just fine as shown here:

```
 nyear = str(input("Enter new Year: "))
 if nyear[0:2] != "20" or nyear.__len__() > 4:
     print("Sorry incorrect year. Please try again")
```

So I have been at it for a while now trying to figure out what in the world is going on and can't get there. Decided I would sleep on it but would post the question just in case. If someone could point out what may be wrong that would be awesome! Or tell me the compilers are just being stupid, well I guess that will do as well.

**My function code**

```
def moveFiles(pathList, source, filenameList):
    # moves files to new location
    # counter keeps track of file name position in list
    cnter = 0
    for x in pathList:
        filename = filenameList[cnter]
        #print(x + "\\" + filename)

        # new filename
        if filename.find("PR") == 0:
            newfilename = filename[3:filename.__len__()]
        else:
            newfilename = filename[2:filename.__len__()]

        # checking if file exists and adding numbers to the end if it does
        if os.path.isfile(x + "\\" + newfilename):
            print("File Name exists!!")
            # adding a 1 to the end
            print(newfilename)
            # PROBLEM ON NEXT TWO LINES, also prob. on any line with the following calls
            print(newfilename[0, 3])
            newfilename = newfilename[0, int(newfilename.__len__() - 4)] + " 1.m4a"

            print("Adding 1:", newfilename)
            # once again check if the file exists and adding 1 to the last number
            while os.path.isfile(x + "\\" + newfilename):
                # me testing if maybe i just can't have math operations withing the substring call
                print("File exists again!!")
                num = newfilename.__len__() - 6
                num2 = newfilename.__len__() - 4
                num3 = int(newfilename[num, num2])
                num = newfilename.__len__() - 5
                newfilename = newfilename[0, num] + str(num3 + 1)
                print("Adding 1:", newfilename)

        # moving file and deleting prefix
        if not os.path.isdir(x):
            os.makedirs(x)

        os.rename(source + "\\" + filename, x + "\\" + newfilename)
        cnter += 1
```

Comment: What do you think is `newfilename[0, 3]`? And **please** do not ever call `newfilename.__len__()`! It is `len(newfilename)`.

Comment: The syntax for a slice (i.e. substring) is `newfilename[0:3]`, not `newfilename[0,3]`. When you give `0,3` inside the square-brackets, python interprets it as _one tuple_, rather than as _start and end indices_.

Comment: oh wow.... I feel so stupid :( I don't know how I did not see that. Well sorry to waste anyone time :| that's what I get when you code late at night. Thanks though!

Comment: Now that this is resolved, you should close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```py
print(newfilename[0:3])
```